# ASP.Net 2015 fails to compile SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have used the following SignalR code for a year, and today it fails compilation with 121 CS0246 errors of the form "The type or namespace name 'Hub' could not be found......".Specific errors in the following snippet are:

(1)HubName: "the type or namespace HubNameAttribute cannot be found.."
(2)Hub: "the type or namespace Hub cannot be found"
(3)GlobalHost: "the name does not exist in the current context.

Note also that "using "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR is greyed out and I don't know why. One thread that I read recommended prepending it to "Hub" but when I do, it does not work, and Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR does not appear to support an object "Hub". Appreciate any suggestions; it was hard enough getting SignalR going, a year ago!

Edit: since posting I believe the problem lies in Owin and ASP.NET 4.5. I appear to be targetting 4.0 and am trying to find out how to upgrade it.

Nope, that didn't work, am now on 4.6 and Owin says that it is current on 3.1 and still Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR is greyed out. Am I missing a reference??

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalR
{
    [HubName("SeekerHub")]
    public class SeekerHub : Hub
    {
        private static Decimal number;

        public static void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            var hubContext = 
            GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<SeekerHub>();
```

Comment: just reinstall all NuGet  packages and see what is happpening https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/reinstalling-and-updating-packages

Comment: Anirudha thanks for your reply. I spend the day uninstalling and reinstalling every NuGet package. Finally discovered Owin2 and at the end of the day I am down to 7 errors, all related to SignalR. they are: "GlobalHost" does not exist...,  "Hub" ,  "Hubname", 'HubnameAttribute" could not be found. 
None of the SignalR packages (nor EPPlus) appear in References.

I believe it has to be related to .net 4.6 or inconsistent versions of Owin/SignalR. SignalR is 2.2.1 and Owin is 3.1.0 but I really don't know what to try next!